# How to select an item in dropdownlist automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdownlists with different items. If I select an item in dropdownlist1, that selected item should get added in dropdownlist2 and it should be selected. 
Using below javascript code, I could able to add the item in dropdownlist2, but its not getting selected. Please let me know how to select the newly added item automatically.

```
var domName = document.getElementById("dropdownlist1");
var domSelectedText = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].text;
var domSelectedValue = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].value;
var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.text = domSelectedText;
opt.value = domSelectedValue;
document.getElementById("dropdownlist2").options.add(opt);
```

Comment: You can set .selectedIndex to the index of your new option, i.e. options.length - 1

Comment: `opt.selected = true`

Comment: opt.selected = true gave me solution. Thank you squint. Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need one more line to mark the newly added item as selected.

```
opt.selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce your code down to just this:

```
var domName = document.getElementById("dropdownlist1"),
selectedOption = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].cloneNode(true);

document.getElementById("dropdownlist2").appendChild(selectedOption);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/utiril/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're making life way more difficult than it needs to be. Consider cloning the node instead of copying it:

```
var domName = document.getElementById("dropdownlist1");

if (domName.selectedIndex >= 0) {
  var opt = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].cloneNode(true);
  opt.selected = true;
  document.getElementById("dropdownlist2").appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: Wow, we came to almost the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var opt = new Option(domSelectedText, domSelectedValue)
Array.prototype.push.call(document.getElementById("dropdownlist2").options, opt)
```

Comment: And watch it fail in IE. Don't treat host objects like native objects, they are not required to behave per ECMA-262. Using DOM methods to append the new option is more efficient and robust (and less to type).

Answer (score 0):

```
var domName = document.getElementById("dropdownlist1");
var domSelectedText = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].text;
var domSelectedValue = domName.options[domName.selectedIndex].value;
var sel2 = document.getElementById("dropdownlist2");
sel2.options[sel2.options.length]=new Option(domSelectedText,domSelectedValue)
sel2.selectedIndex = sel2.options.length-1;
```